# color on specific text without using span

Tags: html, css

My client doesn't want me to use span tag.

How can I make the specific text on a paragraph like the image below?

Thank you so much

[image]

Comment: _My client doesn't want me to use span tag._ Why wouldn't he want for you to use `span` elements?

Comment: Does your client had fight with span?

Comment: Agree with the others, that doesnt seem to make sense since `span` is perfect for this task. As someone stated in an answer you could use a `div` make make it inline but then you may as well use a `span`.

Comment: I really don't know why he doesn't want to use span tag lol it is very useful. for seo purposes he said

Comment: I'm not a SEO guru but I believe that a `header` element with `display: inline` style would suit better then using a `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `div` with style: `display:inline`

example:

```
normal text 
<div style="display:inline;color:red;">this is red color</div> 
this is normal text
```

Comment: how does using `div` helps if her client won't let her use `span`? aren't they basically doing the same thing?